# Query values from a Post Object Repeater

Tags: posts, advanced-custom-fields

I have a repeater field for Post Objects from which I want to obtain the title, excerpt and featured img values. So, these are NOT sub_fields, just common fields.

If I use the example code:

```
<?php
$post_objects = get_field('articulos_repeater');
if( $post_objects ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $post_objects as $post_object): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_object->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($post_object->ID); ?></a>
            <span>Post Object Custom Field: <?php the_field('field_name', $post_object->ID); ?></span>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;

?>
```

I get the values of the current page. But if I

```
print_r($post_object)
```

I get the (in this case) four individual array objects I need.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I think something is wrong with your foreach loop. Can you post the contents of $post_objects right after you do the get_field?

Comment: Hi, @gdaniel The result is an array with nested array objects, one for each of the related posts.

Comment: I asked because if you look at the functions you are using, their default 'ID' parameter is the global post, so it's as if the $post_object->ID is empty and it's defaulting to the global post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this alternative way of getting the post objects. Seeing as your loop seems to be using the global post data anyway, this method uses `setup_postdata` to set the global values.

```
$post_objects = get_field('post_objects');

if( $post_objects ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $post_objects as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
        <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <span>Post Object Custom Field: <?php the_field('field_name'); ?></span>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
<?php endif;
```

Reference: [ACF Post Object documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/)